# Google Material Bar Chart stops working when using a base href

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using [Material Bar Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Material). However, it turns out that whenever I use a 'base href' on my page, the chart will not function properly (if you hover over the bars they disappear). You can try this out with the code below. The base href does not affect inclusion of the required files at Google (but I imagine there is some CSS being included through the javascript that uses relative paths).

I really want to use a base href. Any idea how to make it function?

IMAGE (mouse is hovering over the first bar, which then disappears):

[image]

FUNCTIONAL (no base href):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
  ['2014', 1000, 400, 200]
  ]);

  var options = {
    bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

NOT FUNCTIONAL (base href introduced):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<base href="http://yahoo.com/" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
  ['2014', 1000, 400, 200]
  ]);

  var options = {
    bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, using chrome

Comment: Same issue here (2 years later). It's happening on Firefox I guess. I haven't found any other references to this problem. Did you solve it anytime? I think i will use another graph engine seeing the "material google charts" are still in beta anyway.

Comment: No, I never solved it... I also moved away from this library in the end.